# Is there a way to get the "Pointer" on "OnPointerEnter" in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am working with VR in Unity trying to get my controllers to vibrate when entering a menu image. I have a test script right now trying to see if I can get the pointer that is entering the image because I need to know which controller my raycast is coming from so I can vibrate that controller.

Currently this is my code for testing and I have checked the documentation for the "PointerEventData" but have not found a way to get the pointer from there. This test script is on the image gameobject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class OnPointerEnterEvent : EventTrigger
{

    public override void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnPointerEnter called.");
    }

}
```

Is there anything I am missing here or is this just the wrong way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

With VR as there isn't a screen surface, nor there is one pointer, the area can be tricky. I would recommend looking into unity XR framework / examples, there's a new pair of hover enter/exit callbacks:

XRBaseControllerInteractor.OnHoverEnter(XRBaseInteractable)
XRBaseControllerInteractor.OnHoverExit(XRBaseInteractable)

(where basecontrollerinteractor is usually an XRRayInteractor)

After testing pretty much all vr frameworks I could get to work, I found this to be the most reliable way of handling those events

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it

Answer (score -1):

With PointerEventData.pointerEnter you recieve the object that received 'OnPointerEnter' event. That gameobject should be your controller in the scene.